# How to manually insert a repository in source.list?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, repository

I tried to add a new APT repository using this command:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
```

but I got a "command not found" error. I tried installing `python-software-properties`, but it's already installed:

```
root@debian:~# apt-get install python-software-properties
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-software-properties is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So I decided to add the repository manually to `source.list`, but don't know how. How can I edit `source.list` directly?

Comment: See the answer by @Broam and others at http://askubuntu.com/questions/38021/how-to-add-a-ppa-on-a-server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you visit the [PPA's page](https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/atareao) it'll show you what lines to manually insert into the `source.list`

Click on Technical Details which reveals the following

[image]

Choose your Ubuntu version and copy/paste the lines into the bottom of your `source.list` file.

Comment: Nice, thx Marco :)

Answer (score 3):

One year after your post, I had the same issue on Ubuntu 12.10
I figured out how to bypass the problem (not really to fix it) so I take the time to post a reply just for the record. We never know, if anybody face this problem after me.

**The FIX** (kind of)

```
apt-get install software-properties-common
```

**The explaination** (kind of)

> It *seems* there is a dependancy issue on this package(s)
>   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1024408

**Proof** (kind of)

> You can see the python-software-properties doesn't include the
>   add-apt-repository binary :
>
> ```
> dpkg -L python-software-properties
> ```
>
> While the software-properties-common does :
>
> ```
> dpkg -L software-properties-common
> ```